# Working with OptionsMenu in nested fragment

Tags: android, menu, nested, fragment

I use a NavigationDrawer pattern that is implemented in my hostactivity *MenuActivity*. My navigation has 3 items: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3.
Each itemis bonded to a fragment.

When I click on Item 1, I displayed a fragment A that implements a ViewPager with several fragments (nested fragments).

In my nested fragments, I inflate a menu with the following method (It works fine !) :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

But when I click on another element of my menu (Item 2 -> display Fragment B or Item 3->display Fragment C), **my menu (which was inflated in my nested fragment) is always visible but I want it to disappear.**

Would you have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41587203/1790537

Answer (score 2):

Just save child fragment and then override setMenuVisability:

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (savedFragment!= null)
            savedFragment.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    }
```

it works for me

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this problem, I solved it by setting `setHasOptionMenu(true)` for both the child fragment and the "root" fragment. If the "root" fragment or another child fragment doesn't use option items, it's fine anyway, since you only inflate a menu in the child fragment needing it.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the problem and solved it by the following:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyOptionsMenu() {
    this.setMenuVisibility(false);
    super.onDestroyOptionsMenu();
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroyOptionsMenu");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    onDestroyOptionsMenu();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

I noticed that [onDestroyOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyOptionsMenu()) is not being called so what I only did is call it from the [OnDestroyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView()) method and I set the menu visibility to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach from SafiS answer:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(...) {
    View view = ...

    setMenuVisibility(true);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    setMenuVisibility(false);

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `setRetainInstance(true)` and `setHasOptionMenu(true)` in `onCreate()` in fragment.