# Working with OptionsMenu in nested fragment not updating

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar, android-nested-fragment

I displayed a fragment A that implements a ViewPager with several fragments (nested fragments).

In my nested fragments, I inflate a menu with the following method.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32015042/2634966). And i tried all the answers its not working.

**My issue is**
Everything working fine.but when i open another fragment(it have not any option menu) and get back to previous view pager fragment while clicking menu item onOptionsItemSelected not firing. When i swipe fragment in viewpager and come back to the previous one, when i click menu item its firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because viewpager maintain 3 fragment alive at a time. so when you come back, it set menu visibility status true to last fragment. thats why your menu item click not firing.

Use the following in the fragment where you keeping a viewpager in your case fragment A.

```
private boolean isInitial=true;

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!isInitial) {
            int pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
            if (pageAdapter.getItem(pos).getUserVisibleHint() && pageAdapter.getItem(pos).isVisible()) {
                pageAdapter.getItem(pos).setMenuVisibility(true);
            }
        } else {
            isInitial = false;
        }
    }
```